# How To Set Class Method in sigaction sa_sigaction?

Tags: c++, multithreading, signals, c++17

I have a class and I want to set the class method as an argument of sigaction because I need to use some class attributes:

```cpp
class MyClass {
    void action(int sn, siginfo_t* t, void* ctx) {
        ...
    }
};

int main() {
    MyClass c;
    struct sigaction sig_action;
    sig_action.sa_sigaction = c.action;   // ERROR!
}
```

Even I've tried to use `std::bind` with `reinterpret_cast` but didn't work.

So, how can I set `sa_sigaction` a class method?

NOTE: it **SHOULD** be a class method and not a static method or a function.

Comment: sad, last `void*` is not for user data, but for `context` which doesn't have neither userdata.

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look at declaration of `sigaction::sa_sigaction`, you'll find that it is `void (*)(int,siginfo_t*,void*)`. This is a pointer to function.

> NOTE: it SHOULD be a class method and not a static method or a function.

It cannot be, because pointers to functions can not point to non-static member functions. You must pass a pointer to a non-member or a static member function as the signal handler. That function may in turn call the non-static member function if you so desire (as long as the function is async signal safe).

> I need to use some class attributes

Make sure that those attributes are of type `volatile sig_atomic_t`.

Answer (score 0):

```
class MyClass {
    void action(int sn, siginfo_t* t, void* ctx) {
        ...
    }
};

MyClass c;

void action(int sn, siginfo_t* t, void* ctx) {
    c.action(sn, t, ctx);
}

int main() {
    struct sigaction sig_action;
    sig_action.sa_sigaction = action;
}
```

Comment: *"the behavior is undefined if the signal handler refers to any object with static storage duration that is not `std::atomic` or volatile `std::sig_atomic_t` (until C++17)"* `c` is a static object of neither type, so the behaviour is undefined prior to C++17. The rules seem to have been relaxed in C++17 and this seems to be well defined as far as I can tell.

Comment: @eerorika Exactly. The OP tagged the question with C++17.